# Integrating Mathjax in Android

Tags: javascript, android, webview, mathjax

I want to implement MathJax in my android app thru Webview as below:

```
            holder.webViewEquation.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://bar/", "<script type='text/x-mathjax-config'>"
                    + "MathJax.Hub.Config({ "
                    + "showMathMenu: false, "
                    + "jax: ['input/TeX','output/HTML-CSS'], "
                    + "showProcessingMessages: false, "
                    + "messageStyle: 'none', "
                    + "extensions: ['tex2jax.js'], "
                    + "TeX: { extensions: ['AMSmath.js','AMSsymbols.js',"
                    + "'noErrors.js','noUndefined.js'] } "
                    + "});</script>"
                    + "<script type='text/javascript' "
                    + "src='file:///android_asset/MathJax/MathJax.js'"
                    + "></script><span id='math'></span>", "text/html", "utf-8", "");
            holder.webViewEquation.setWebViewClient(object : WebViewClient() {
                override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView?, url: String) {
                    super.onPageFinished(view, url)
                    if (!url.startsWith("http://bar")) {
                        return;
                    }
                    holder.webViewEquation.evaluateJavascript("javascript:MathJax.Hub.Queue(['Typeset',MathJax.Hub]);",null);
                    holder.webViewEquation.evaluateJavascript("javascript:document.getElementById('math').innerHTML='\\["
                            + [ x^n + y^n = z^n ]
                            + "\\]';",null);
                }
            })
```

But all I get is a result like `[[x^n+y^n=z^n]]`.

What am I missing? Please can anyone help me with how can I display my latex equation in the proper format on Webview?

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: try switching the order of your two `evaluateJavascript` commands.

Comment: tried that, still i am getting output as i pass as plain text i.e,. [x^n+y^n=z^n] . No formatting as MathJax would do . And after a while in webview itself [Math Processing Error]

Comment: It looks like the backslashes are not getting through to the WebView.  Try changing `\\[` and `\\]` to `\\\\[` and `\\\\]`.  You are going through two levels of escaping (one for the strings in the app itself, and one for the javascript that is being created).

Comment: No i tried that earlier, it did not work out @DavideCervone .I tried putting $$ in between too, no luck. Finally what i am doing is i found a helper class where Webview is extended & Mathjax config can be passed which works. But what i wanted was to get it work in above way. For some reason i am missing something here!